# Can standard container templates be instantiated with incomplete types?

Tags: c++, templates, stl, incomplete-type

Sometimes it's useful to instantiate a standard container with an incomplete type to obtain a recursive structure:

```
struct multi_tree_node { // Does work in most implementations
    std::vector< multi_tree_node > child;
};

struct trie_node { // Does not work in most implementations
    std::map< char, trie_node > next;
};
```

This tends to work because containers don't have members of type `value_type` or member functions that pass or return any `value_type` objects by value. The Standard doesn't seem to say very much about incomplete template arguments, but there is one bit under C++11 §17.6.4.8 [lib.res.on.functions], "requirements on other functions":

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: … if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Does this make the above constructs illegal, even though the instantiations are not in block scope? Does this fall under "operations on types used to instantiate standard library template components" (also 17.6.4.8)? Or is a library implementation forbidden to incur template instantiations that might fail for incomplete types when all specifically required instantiations succeed?

**Edit:** Since only functions may call and instantiate other functions, restricting "operations on types…" to those in block scope would seem to hold the contents of member functions to a stricter requirement than the contents of signatures and member class definitions. After all, it certainly doesn't make sense to *do anything* with a `multi_tree_node` until the type is complete. And this extends to the `std::unique_ptr` which explicitly supports an incomplete type argument, *even when used in block scope*.

**Edit 2:** Serves me right for not bothering to test the `trie_node` example — and I've even tried it before. It's the same as the example of breakage in [the article](http://drdobbs.com/184403814) that @Ise linked. However, while the article seems to take for granted that "nothing like that could work," the solution seems simple to me — `std::map`'s internal `tree_node` class should be a non-member template, not a member non-template class.

Anyway, that article establishes design intent pretty well, so I guess my nitpick about being under the subheading of "requirements on functions" is only just that.

Comment: I don't see any incomplete types in the code you've posted?

Comment: @JohnDibling: `trie_node` is incomplete while defining `next`.

Comment: @JohnDibling Inside a class' own scope, it is incomplete.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210286/incomplete-class-usage-in-template

Comment: Btw, it's `[17.4.3.6]` in the C++03 standard, for anyone interested. Also, best also add the tag under which the paragraph goes, in this case `[lib.res.on.functions]`.

Comment: To summarize Björn's link — template instantiation proceeds by lazy evaluation, so the contents of member functions and member templates are only "seen" upon their first use. However, function signatures and non-template member class definitions must be valid given any incomplete arguments.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Just for your information,
[this article](http://drdobbs.com/184403814) seems to
explain the related issue.

Comment: @IseWisteria Thanks, if you just put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Thanks, please give me a minute!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I feel the wording *instantiating* in 17.6.4.8/2 is a little
ambiguous, but according to 
[this article](http://drdobbs.com/184403814),
the standard's intent seems not to allow recursive data type using
standard containers.

On a related note, VC2005 issues an error for
`class C { std::deque< C > x; };`, while it compiles
`class C { std::vector< C > x; };`...
However, in my understanding, this restriction is just for expanding the
freedom of the implementation of standard containers.
So as *Kerrek SB* mentioned, there can be containers which allow
recursive data structure, and
[Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html)
seems to provide this facility.

Answer (score 11):

Here's my attempt at an interpretation:

The standard simply says you mustn't do this, even though any given concrete implementation may have no problem supporting such a construction. But imagine for example if someone wanted to write a "small vector" optimization by which a vector always contains space for, say, five elements. Immediately you'd be in trouble because you'd have a self-referential type. This would be a problem even if the vector employed some sort of static branching depending on the size of the value type.

Therefore, in order to not preclude implementations from including such constructions, the standard simply says that you must only use complete types. In other words, the fact that most containers only contain references or pointers to the value type is an implementation detail rather than a standard requirement.

<sub>Just to clarify this: if you define your *own* class template, it is perfectly possible to design it in such a way that it explicitly supports incomplete types. An example from the standard is `std::unique_ptr`, which is perfectly happy with the incomplete type parameter `T[]` (or even `void`).</sub>

Comment: +1 great example, but I'm going to wait for some ab initio standardese interpretation… my code certainly violates the quoted requirement, but the other part of the question is whether or how the requirement applies outside a function/block scope. (Since only functions may call and instantiate other functions, this would seem to hold the contents of member functions to a different standard than the contents of signatures and member class definitions.)

Comment: "small vector" is not a great example; that optimization is not allowed by the standard.

Answer (score 4):

In general, using an incomplete type as a template parameter to a standard library component is UB. Here's the [reference](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/res.on.functions#2.5):

> If an incomplete type ([basic.types]) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component or evaluating a concept, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Note that since c++17, explicit permission has been granted to `std::vector` to allow incomplete types. Here's the [reference](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/vector.overview#4):

> An incomplete type T may be used when instantiating vector if the allocator meets the allocator completeness requirements. T shall be complete before any member of the resulting specialization of vector is referenced.

So in your example, `multi_tree_node` is well formed, but `trie_node` is UB.