# Instantiation of a list with an incomplete type in a typedef

Tags: templates, typedef, clang, libc++

I have a problem with compiling llvm. The problem is that my current compiler (clang + libc++) tries to instantiate a template before the template parameter gets defined. Here is the code example:

```
// ----- TYPEDEFS -----
class NodeEntry;
class EdgeEntry;

typedef std::list<NodeEntry> NodeList;
typedef std::list<EdgeEntry> EdgeList;

typedef NodeList::iterator NodeItr; // line 39 
typedef NodeList::const_iterator ConstNodeItr;

typedef EdgeList::iterator EdgeItr;
typedef EdgeList::const_iterator ConstEdgeItr;

typedef std::list<EdgeItr> AdjEdgeList;

typedef AdjEdgeList::iterator AdjEdgeItr;

class NodeEntry {
private:  
  AdjEdgeList adjEdges;
  ...
};

class EdgeEntry {
private:
  AdjEdgeItr node1AEItr, node2AEItr;
  ...
};
```

The error from the compiler is this:

```
error: field has incomplete type 'PBQP::Graph::NodeEntry'

/Developer/Extras/llvm/include/llvm/CodeGen/PBQP/Graph.h:39:13: note: in instantiation of template class
  'std::__1::list<PBQP::Graph::NodeEntry, std::__1::allocator<PBQP::Graph::NodeEntry> >' requested here
typedef NodeList::iterator NodeItr;
        ^
/Developer/Extras/llvm/include/llvm/CodeGen/PBQP/Graph.h:31:11: note: forward declaration of 'PBQP::Graph::NodeEntry'
class NodeEntry;
```

As far as I can tell the compiler tries to instantiate `std::list<NodeEntry>` in order to get the iterator. This fails as NodeEntry is not defined yet. And of course EdgeEntry is using NodeEntry and vice versa.

The obvious question is: How do I fix it?
The educational question is: Why does the compiler try to instantiate the template when defining the type? Should it not wait until we do something with the list?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems to compile fine with clang++ 3.0 and libc++ (svn version 154095) on linux.

Comment: Interesting. According to clang website [the feature is not supported](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#undep_incomplete)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want guaranteed support for incomplete types, your best bet is to create `unique_ptr`'s to them:

```
typedef std::list<std::unique_ptr<NodeEntry>> NodeList;
typedef std::list<std::unique_ptr<EdgeEntry>> EdgeList;
```

In the past, many times `std::list<incomplete_type>` would just work.  However with C++11 and `noexcept` specifications, it is becoming more likely that a complete type is needed, just so that the `noexcept` spec can be validated.

C++11 guarantees that `unique_ptr<incomplete_type>` and `shared_ptr<incomplete_type>` will work, although there are strict limits.  For example wherever `~unique_ptr()` is executed, the type has to be complete there.  But you can usually outline such code to a source and #include the complete type at that point.

`unique_ptr<incomplete_type>` and `shared_ptr<incomplete_type>` are the only class templates in the C++11 std::lib that are guaranteed to work with incomplete types.  Everything else is undefined behavior:

[res.on.functions]/p2/b5:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> ...
>
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

If for some reason the `std::list` does not need to own the pointer to the incomplete type, then `std::list<NodeEntry*>` would work even better.  You might also want to entertain using `vector` instead of `list` since the cost of moving pointers (or even `unique_ptr`'s) around is relatively small.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#undep_incomplete) also already linked, they are not willing to support incomplete types for stl containers in libc++.

Something funny that stems from this is the following code will not compile with libc++:

```
#include <list>

struct Tree {
    // ... more stuff ...
    std::list<Tree> mChildren;
};
```

but this code compiles fine, because list's template parameter also depends on a template parameter:

```
template<typename T>
struct TreeT {
    // ... more stuff ...
private:
    std::list<TreeT<T> > mChildren;
};
```

This strikes me as odd, since the latter is more complex.

On a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333633/506584), which also contains a reference to the ISO section concerning incomplete types in templates, [Boost.Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html) is mentioned as an alternative because it explicitly allows recursive data structures.  I came across this post while diagnosing a similar problem and this is my solution for now.