# How can I forward declare a type I'm going to create with typedef?

Tags: c++, typedef, forward-declaration

For example, take this snippet of code:

```
class Foo;
class Something {
    Foo *thing;
};
typedef std::vector<Something> Foo;
```

This doesn't compile, because `Foo` is already a type when the `typedef` is hit. However, I think it shows my use case; I have cyclical dependencies and need one to fulfill the other, but (currently) one of the things is typedef'd. I'd prefer not to write something like

```
class Foo {
    std::vector<Something> inside;
}
```

because then I need to remember the `inside` in every `my_foo.inside.some_method()`. I'd also like to avoid writing a wrapper around `std::vector<Something>`, because it'd be a lot of boilerplate.

**How can I forward declare a type which I'm defining with a `typedef`?** Alternatively, how can I resolve my problem of cyclical dependencies *without* using one of the solutions above? Is it possible at all?

Note that I'm not asking "How can I `typedef` with a type that hasn't been declared yet". I'm asking "How can I use `typedef` to define a previously-declared type".

Comment: Apologies if any of the terminology is off. I never really learned it. Please feel free to correct me or question assumptions that seem to be false.

Comment: `typedef Foo;` maybe

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre IIRC that's a compile error

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Huh??

Comment: Suggestion for more consistent/harmoneous code; forget about `typedef`, use `using` - `using Foo = std::vector<Something>;`. Doesn't help with your question, just wanted to mention it ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Forward declare the class instead:

```
class Something;
typedef std::vector<Something> Foo;
class Something { Foo *thing; };
```

If you are using C++11 revision or greater, use an `using` declaration in place of a `typedef`:

```
class Something;
using Foo = std::vector<Something>;
class Something { Foo *thing; };
```

And that's all.

Comment: ...oh. Duh. I'm smart.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use `using` over `typedef`? I know it matters when you want to use templated nicknames, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I'd say _because we are living the 2016_, but it's also far clearer to me as a declaration.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747810/what-is-the-difference-between-typedef-and-using-in-c11 - also, looks more similar to `using namespace foo;` and `using foo::bar;` - just nice to keep to one keyword :)

Comment: Are you sure this is legal? You can't create a standard container of forward declared objects, which seems to be exactly what's going on here.

Comment: @MarkB But typedefs don't need complete types. It has to be a complete type when _used_, and it is -- the forward-declared class is defined immediately after the typedef, before any code that uses either it or them.

Comment: @MarkB Yes, I'm sure it is legal, but [you can try it for yourself](https://godbolt.org/g/2xySwq).

Comment: @QPaysTaxes What I'm seeing is that `Something` has a pointer to a `vector<Something>`, and *inside the definition of `Something`*, `Something` is not fully defined. @skypjack I'm asking if you can provide the standard reference showing it's *legal* not showing that a particular compiler can compile it.

Comment: @MarkB Apart for the fact that you can try it with more than _a particular compiler_, I'll find for you the sections in the reference that you are asking fot (as soon as I can, it's past 22 in Italy).

Comment: @MarkB [Here](http://eel.is/c++draft/containers#vector.overview-3) we are (maybe) - _An incomplete type T may be used when instantiating vector_.

Comment: @MarkB Oh, I see. That's not actually the use case; I'm actually taking a reference to the typedef'd type (for more reasons than just that), so it all works out

Comment: @MarkB: incomplete type for vector was supported by most compiler even if standard stated (indirectly ?) that it was UB. Should be allowed in C++17. See [can-i-manage-incomplete-class-objects-using-stl-containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858878/can-i-manage-incomplete-class-objects-using-stl-containers)

Comment: @Jarod42 Fair enough. I got the reference from the working draft indeed.