# Template instantiation, two-phase name lookup, different behavior with automatic deduced type

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++14, name-lookup

After seeing this question [When is a C++ template instantiation type checked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34204483/2805305) , and wondering myself for quite some time the same thing I started to play with code to assimilate the knowledge. The answer gives clear and correct explanation. It mentions two-phase name lookup and the fact that the end of translation unit is also considered a point of instantiation for function templates. However I observed different behavior when using automatic return type deduction:

This is like the original code. It is correct and works as explained in the linked post:

```
class A;
class B;

template <class T> auto foo() -> T * {
  A *pa = nullptr; // ignore pa being `nullptr`.
  return static_cast<T *>(pa);
}

auto test() { return foo<B>(); }

class A {};
class B : public A {};
```

When using automatic return type deduction for the template `foo`, the definitions of `A` and `B` must appear before the instantiation point of `foo`:

Not working:

```
class A;
class B;

template <class T> auto foo()  { // automatic return type deduction
  A *pa = nullptr;
  return static_cast<T *>(pa);
}

auto test() { return foo<B>(); }

class A {};
class B : public A {};
```

The error by gcc (4.9 and 5.2.1):

> error: invalid static_cast from type ‘A*’ to type ‘B*’

Clang gives a similar error

Working:

```
class A;
class B;

template <class T> auto foo()  { // automatic return type deduction
  A *pa = nullptr;
  return static_cast<T *>(pa);
}

class A {};
class B : public A {};

auto test() { return foo<B>(); }
```

Why it is happening? Why is that the rule about the end of compilation unit beeing considered a point of instantiation doesn't make the template instantiation legitimate anymore?

Comment: For extra confusion, what if we give `B` a member of type `decltype(test());`?

Comment: Pardon me but I don't see anything peculiar here at the point of instantiation (i.e., `foo<B>()`) `B` and `A` are incomplete types. Thus, the compiler complains.

Comment: @101010 But it works when `foo` has an explicit return type, even if `A` and `B` are incomplete types at the point if instantiation. See first example and the linked post.

Comment: blah trailing return types...

Comment: There are two points of instantiations of `foo<B>`, one immediately after `test`, one at the end of the TU. The cast is invalid at the first point but not the second, so this looks like it's ill-formed NDR. The reason for the error showing up in only the deduced return type case is likely that the compiler needed to determine the return type of `test` (which isn't a template) and so it instantiated the body of `foo` at the first point rather than the second point.

Comment: @T.C. [temp.res]/8 does not apply, and the ODR does not consider the instantiated functions in both cases to be distinct. Why would it be ill-formed, NDR?